# Django not displaying database items

Tags: python, html, django, database

I have created a project named Test and an app named testing inside this app. I have a model named ModelTesting in the testing app. This model has only one field named prop, which is a CharField of max_length=20. I can insert the items in database without any issue but cannot display them in the homepage. Take a look at my code.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# My Model
class ModelTesting(models.Model):
    prop = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.prop
```

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ModelTesting

# Loads Homepage
def index(request):
    all_testing_models = ModelTesting.objects.all()
    params = {'all_models': all_testing_models}
    return render(request, "index.html", params)
```

And here is the bootstrap template in which I want to display the items. Also, I have edited the template myself.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>The Properties are:-</h1>
        
    {% for test_model in all_testing_mdoels %}
        <h3>{{test_model.prop}}</h3>
    {% endfor %}

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This error has occurred in some other projects as well, so I created this project specifically for this purpose. Please take a look and help me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing `all_models` in

```
    params = {'all_models': all_testing_models}
```

and trying to look for `all_testing_models` in

```
    {% for test_model in all_testing_mdoels %}
        <h3>{{test_model.prop}}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
```

Fix either one to match the other.

You may wish to turn on [`string_if_invalid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables) to help you catch typos better.